# How closure is forming for the setTimeOut in the below scenario

Tags: javascript, closures

**closure** is formed when we can reach that code, thus it is not garbage collected. having said that

```
function outer(){
  var name = "ankit";
    function inner(){
         ...
    }
  return inner
}
```

Now to form a closure for the above scenario, we have to store the reference of inner, so that execution context of that particular execution of outer is not garbage collected and we have a closure.

some thing like:

```
let closure = outer(); // name can be accessed
```

Now I am confused regarding this example for setTimeout

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
  timeer(i)
}
timer(i){
 setTimeOut((i) => {console.log(i)}, i*1000);
}
```

// prints 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...

Now how the above code works, I understand there is an implicit closure created by setTimeOut, but we are not storing the reference of setTimeOut declaration, so the execution scope of timer execution for a particular i should be garbage collected?
Please help me understanding this use case. Is javascript environment implicitly store reference setTimeOut?

Comment: `name can be accessed` are you sure? How would you access the `var name` using `closure`? or `outer` for that matter

Comment: I mean, inside 'inner' function

Comment: inner(){ console.log(name); } // closure() will log name

Comment: `i` is entered into the variable environment of `timer`'s execution context because it is an argument of the function, assuming the definition is actually `function timer(i){...` and not just `timer(i){...`. Also, since there is a use in the task queue for `i`, none of that environment will be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @TravisJ, yes 'i' will be in execution context, but how javascript run time finds out whether it is used in the task queue ? so that it is not garbage collected. till the time setTimeOut will be triggered, call stack will be empty, isn't or M missing something?

Comment: May be since setTimeOut declaration is available on Window Object, calling setTimeout inside a function creates a implicit closure, that can be the reason why execution context of outer function containing a setTimeOut is not garbage collected.

Comment: Are you asking why the callback to `setTimeout` is not garbage collected before it gets executed?

Comment: @vlaz,yes when setTimeOut is executed, for remembering 'i', a closure should be formed so that execution context of 'timer' function for a particular 'i' is not garbage collected. Since when setTimeOut is executed call stack will be empty.